# Iterative Deepening Search in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to implement Iterative Deeping Search. I do not know what I am doing wrong, but I don't seem to be getting it right. I always end up with an infinite loop.
Can anyone point out my mistake?
I implemented the Depth-Limited Search and used it in my IDS code. DLS seems to be working fine on its own, but I do not understand IDS and why i'm ending up in an infinite loop.

```
public class IterativeDeepeningSearch<T>  where T : IComparable
{
    string closed;

    public int maximumDepth;
    public int depth = 0;
    bool Found = false;
    Stack<Vertex<T>> open;

    public IterativeDeepeningSearch()
    {
        open = new Stack<Vertex<T>>();
    }

    public bool IDS(Vertex<T> startNode, Vertex<T> goalNode)
    {
        // loops through until a goal node is found
        for (int _depth = 0; _depth < Int32.MaxValue; _depth++)
        {
            bool found = DLS(startNode, goalNode, _depth);
            if (found)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // this will never be reached as it 
        // loops forever until goal is found
        return false;
    }

    public bool DLS(Vertex<T> startNode, Vertex<T> goalNode, int _maximumDepth)
    {
        maximumDepth = _maximumDepth;

        open.Push(startNode);  

        while (open.Count > 0 && depth < maximumDepth)    
        {
            Vertex<T> node = open.Pop();    

            closed = closed + " " + node.Data.ToString();
            if (node.Data.ToString() == goalNode.Data.ToString())
            {
                Debug.Write("Success");
                Found = true;
                break;

            }

            List<Vertex<T>> neighbours = node.Neighbors;   

            depth++;    

            if (neighbours != null)
            {
                foreach (Vertex<T> neighbour in neighbours)
                {
                    if (!closed.Contains(neighbour.ToString()))
                        open.Push(neighbour);   
                }
                Debug.Write("Failure");
            }


        }
        Console.WriteLine(closed);
        return Found;
    }

}
}
```

PS: My Vertex Class just has two properties, Data and Children

Comment: As Simone said, you are calling DLS with the wrong argument (use _depth instead of depth). In addition, you should limit the depth upper bound to graph size. You can do it by counting graph nodes in a pre-process.

Comment: `Int32.MaxValue;` means it will not really run forever. Just wait a few years, it'll stop.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop iterates on _depth but in the DLS function you are passing depth, which is always 0

```
    for (int _depth = 0; _depth < Int32.MaxValue; _depth++)
    {
        bool found = DLS(startNode, goalNode, depth);
        if (found)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just changed it, and it's still infinite